# Do I have to invoke `completionHandler` for remote notifications received when the app is in the foreground on iOS 7+?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Pre-iOS 7, if an app receives a remote notification while it’s in the foreground, `-[UIApplicationDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:]` is called; if the app is in the background, that method is called when the user launches the app from the notification. On iOS 7 and later, if the app has the appropriate capabilities and implements `-[UIApplicationDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:]`, all remote notifications are sent to that method.

If the app is in the background and the remote notification payload contains the key-value pair `{ content-available: 1 }`, the app is awoken to allow it to fetch new content. When the fetch is complete, the app is meant to invoke `completionHandler` with one of three values to indicate the result of the fetch (`UIBackgroundFetchNewContent`, etc.).

Do I have to invoke `completionHandler` for remote notifications received when the app is in the foreground on iOS 7+? and if so, which value should I use as an argument?